# Java FX замена текста в Label

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, java-8

Прошу помочь с Java FX

есть Label и хочу менять текст в нём

тут инициализация

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в классе есть функция, которую хочу вызывать в других классах

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в когда хочу вызвать функцию с другого класса, например с Main

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то выписывает ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы ловите NPE. Вам нужно пробывать узать platform run later ,и кстати НИКОГДА не вставляйте код как картинку.

Comment: Вот посмотрите тут : https://stackoverflow.com/q/218384/5723492

Comment: перед тем,как начать писать какой-то код нужно изучит самые фундаментальные правила и принципы. например, правила именования. переменные и методы всегда именуются с маленькой буквы,а классы-с большой. думаете это мелочи?я вам приведу пример. ваше исключение  выбрасывается на строке Controller.printOnLable().исходя из того,как это написано, вы вызываете статический метод printOnLable() у класса Controller,но так же не может быть.значит это перемнная с именем Controller,которую вы почему-то написали с большой буквы? добавьте сюда скриншоты случайных фрагментов кода. результат - вопрос без ответа

Comment: @Дмитрий Controller  - это класс, потому с большой

Comment: тогда непонятно, почему у вас обращение к label через статику? покажите весь код, только в нормальном виде, не катинками. либо дайте ссылку на гит. иначе проблему не решить